# How to rotate an object around one end of line till its lies on the line

Tags: unity

From the image below, I would like to rotate a game object C around a point A of a line (made using a line renderer) by an angle d to position p1 till C is on the same line joining points A and B over a given period of time. Preferably using a coroutine. Please note that the angle d is not known. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RotateScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed;

    public void StartAlign( Vector3 pointA, Vector3 pointB )
    {
        StartCoroutine( Align(pointA, pointB) );
    }

    private IEnumerator Align( Vector3 pointA, Vector3 pointB )
    {
        // Compute the rotation axis
        Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross( pointB - pointA, transform.position - pointA );

        // Compute the rotation angle
        float totalAngle = -Vector3.SignedAngle(pointB - pointA, transform.position - pointA, axis );
        float sign = totalAngle < 0 ? -1 : 1;
        float angle = 0;

        // Rotates smoothly the object
        for ( float cumulativeAngle = 0 ; sign * cumulativeAngle < sign * totalAngle ; cumulativeAngle += angle )
        {
            angle = sign * Mathf.Min( sign * (totalAngle - cumulativeAngle), Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed );
            transform.RotateAround( pointA, axis, angle );
            yield return null;
        }
    }

}
```

---

If your `pointC` must be a vector, try the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RotateScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed;

    // This is an example function to show how StartAlign must be called
    // The last parameter must be a function taking a Vector3 as only parameter
    public void Foo()
    {
        StartAlign( pointC, pointA, pointB, OnPointCChanged );
    }

    public void StartAlign( Vector3 pointC, Vector3 pointA, Vector3 pointB, System.Action<Vector3> SetNewPointCPosition )
    {
        StartCoroutine( Align( pointC, pointA, pointB, SetNewPointCPosition ) );
    }

    private IEnumerator Align( Vector3 pointC, Vector3 pointA, Vector3 pointB, System.Action<Vector3> SetNewPointCPosition )
    {
        // Compute the rotation axis
        Vector3 direction = pointC - pointA;
        Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross( pointB - pointA, direction );

        Quaternion startRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        Quaternion endRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation( direction, pointB - pointA );

        Debug.Break();

        // Rotates smoothly the object
        for ( float time = 0 ; time < 1 / rotationSpeed ; time += Time.deltaTime )
        {
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Slerp( startRotation, endRotation, time * rotationSpeed );
            Vector3 d = rotation * direction;
            SetNewPointCPosition( d + pointA );

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private void OnPointCChanged( Vector3 newPosition )
    {
        Debug.Log( newPosition );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not too sure how to get the transform for A and B.

Comment: You have to attach this script to the objectC, and then drag & drop the objects A and B into the public fields, in the inspector.

Comment: Okay, maybe I didn't explain it well enough. C is an object but A and B are the end points of a line made with a line renderer.

Comment: My bad, I've edited my answer so that you can pass two vectors as end points of your LineRenderer

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I'd like to know. What happens if A and C are points and also form a line. How would line AC be aligned to line AB?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
If A, B and C are aligned, I guess C won't move, just give a try :)
Please, don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped you solving your problem.

Comment: I was referring to if the original question had two lines AC and AB instead of  an object C. In that case from the image, how would line AC be rotated to line up with line AB?

Comment: I've edited my answer so that `pointC` can be a Vector3.

Comment: In `Foo()` i thought `OnPointCChanged` is suppose to have a parameter.

Comment: No, `OnPointCChanged` is a pointer to the function which be called in the coroutine.

Comment: Okay. The the line AC is not rotating

Comment: You have to put the correct code inside the `OnPointCChanged` function so that to move the line. Since you haven't provided your code, I can't help you (if you want to add it, edit your question)

Comment: @Hellium Please would you take a look at this related question for me https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/160161/a-coroutine-to-rotate-one-point-around-another-by-a-given-angle-without-referrin

Answer (score 0):

The signed angle between two 2d vectors A and B is

```
angle = atan2(-B.y * A.x + B.x * A.y, B.x * A.y + B.y * A.y)
```

If you have a signed angle between the point and the line, then rotating the former towards the latter is as simple as checking for the sign of the angle. If it's positive, then subtract from the current angle. If it's negative, then add to it.

In code (`step` is the angle the point rotates in one frame):

```
IEnumerator Rotate(Vector2 A, Vector2 B) {
    float angle;
    do {
        angle = Mathf.atan2(-B.y * A.x + B.x * A.y, B.x * A.y + B.y * A.y);
        if (angle < 0) {
            // Rotate the point by 1 step in the positive direction
        } else {
            // Rotate the point by 1 step in the negative direction
        }
    } while (angle > step);
    // Set the angle of the point to the angle of the line
}
```

Comment: Please would you take a look at this related question for me https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/160161/a-coroutine-to-rotate-one-point-around-another-by-a-given-angle-without-referrin